# What is the name of framework/library/whatever that is behind Yeoman CLI tool?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, yeoman

I would like to ask you what is behind Yeoman CLI tool (I mean something like http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html or https://github.com/c9s/CLIFramework). Can I use it apart from yeoman in my own console app?

[image: Yeoman CLI tool]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know specifically for yeoman, but [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander) is a really good package for creating command line interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

After considerations on yo's package.json i found that:

Main component to build CLI:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer

Helpers:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk

https://www.npmjs.com/package/meow